# Homebrew upgrade results in clang install every time

Tags: xcode, macos, clang, homebrew

Recently with macos 12.6 - after running

```
homebrew upgrade
```

I was getting a prompt to install clang. I was not paying attention to the console and installed it. But it kept on happening and I kept on installing clang. As this issue might repeat I would like to share my solution

Answer (score 1):

#1 - this is related to xcode unapplied update to OS 16 and it's packages. Launch Xcode and update everything requested

#2 -

```
xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
```

You can also use this command.
Hopefully my steps will solve your issue. Couldn't find solution anywhere, so decided to share it here